# Pandas groupby specific data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of this sort :
sector, name, Date, Price

I would like to aggregate my data so I do to calculate the 3 years volatility :

```
result = (df
          .groupby(['sector', 'name'])
               volat_3Y=('price', lambda x: 100*np.sqrt(252*np.log(x[-3*252:-1] / x[-3*252:-1].shift(1)).var()))            )
```

I would like also to calculate 2020, 2019,... performance but when I try :

```
result = (df
          .groupby(['sector', 'name'])
               volat_3Y=('price', lambda x: 100*np.sqrt(252*np.log(x[-3*252:-1] / x[-3*252:-1].shift(1)).var()))
               perf_2020=('price', lambda x.loc['2020-09-18']) # Just to have access to a specific date 
               )
```

I have an error message. Any suggestion ?

This the error message :

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1600387200000000000

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Data/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
2888             try:
-> 2889                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
2890             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: Timestamp('2020-09-18 00:00:00')

Comment: *I have an error message*, why don't you post the error here?

Comment: I add when I do the same thing within a group it works :
group.get_group(('sect1', 'nom1')).agg(perf_2020=('VL', lambda x: 100*x.loc['2020-09-18']))
I have a number : 
 price
perf_2020 10458.0

Answer (score 0):

This formulation works for me:

```py
result = (
    data
    .set_index('Date')
    .groupby(['Sector', 'Symbol'])
    .agg(
        volat_3Y = (
            'Price',
            lambda x: 100*np.sqrt(252*np.log(x[-3*252:-1] / x[-3*252:-1].shift(1)).var())),
        perf_2020_09_18 = (
            'Price',
            lambda x: x.loc['2020-09-18'])
    )
)
```

Result:

| Sector | Symbol | volatility_3yr | price_2020_09_18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Communication Services | FB | 38.1945 | 252.53 |
| Communication Services | GOOG | 30.7639 | 1459.99 |
| Communication Services | NFLX | 42.3228 | 469.96 |
| Consumer Cyclical | AMZN | 32.613 | 2954.91 |
| Technology | AAPL | 35.5864 | 106.5 |

---

Complete example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import yfinance

symbols = ['FB', 'AMZN', 'AAPL', 'NFLX', 'GOOG']
sectors = [yfinance.Ticker(symbol).info['sector'] for symbol in symbols]
symbols_sectors = dict(zip(symbols, sectors))

raw_data = pdr.get_data_stooq(symbols).Close
data = (
    # get raw data
    raw_data
    # clean up names
    .set_axis(list(raw_data.columns), 1)
    .sort_index()
    .reset_index()
    # transform to long form
    .melt('Date', var_name='Symbol', value_name='Price')
    # attach sector names
    .assign(Sector = lambda x: x.Symbol.map(symbols_sectors))
)

result = (
    data
    .set_index('Date')
    .groupby(['Sector', 'Symbol'])
    .agg(
        volatility_3yr = (
            'Price',
            lambda x: 100*np.sqrt(252*np.log(x[-3*252:-1] / x[-3*252:-1].shift(1)).var())),
        price_2020_09_18 = (
            'Price',
            lambda x: x.loc['2020-09-18'])
    )
)

print(result.reset_index().to_markdown(index=False))
```